# How do I apply the same texture to the bathroom wall after patching a hole?

Tags: bathroom, patching-drywall

My repair guy patched some holes with drywall mud on walls that had been painted with semi-gloss; we went eggshell. He then painted over the area after the mud was supposedly dry.  The area did not match the texture of the rest of the wall and it had tiny bubbles as well as the area looking scratchy from the spreading knife.  I could see these huge flat areas amongst the textured so I tried stippling the bumps back in with a kitchen sponge; maybe way too soon after painting.  I then tried to roller a coat over the area I did.  Now I have dull scratchy areas all over the area, but there is some texture.  What I need is a novice way to prep the walls so I can repaint and I will get a textured shiny wall like I thought I was going to get.  I would like this method to be a good one, but one that does not require expensive supplies or talents I do not have.  Help!

Comment: There are many kinds of textured patterns and different ways to acheive those.  Nobody can help you unless you post pictures of the patched and surrounding area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to repaint the entire wall. When patching, its almost impossible to get a perfect match of texture and color. If the patch is small you might never notice it, but large patches are usually noticeable to some degree.  This might be just because the original paint has cured for a few years (probably yellowed too), or it could be like your case with different textures.

It does however sound like the patch might not have been sanded well enough, so the first step is to sand the patch back down so the surface is smooth and even with the wall.  The prime the spot, and repaint.  If the original wall was painted with a roller, make sure to use a roller again.  A patch that is painted with a brush will usually stand out on a wall that was painted with a roller originally.

Comment: Called McCormick paints - said to spackle in bubbles; let dry; lightly sand. Apply KILZ (primer); lightly sand (100 grd), finish using 4/8" roller (3/8" was used).  Can't remember if guy sanded after mudding (used quick drying mud).  Area looks scraped and has little pitty holes. Maybe not sanded well or painted when mud not totally dry.  Paint not covering well; light pink over darker blue pink; bleeding through. Don't like wide brush marks on edging (2" brush).  I will use tape, edge with 1" brush, roller down to/over tape (he didn't use tape) for more texture than brush mark (my usual way).

Comment: Steven:  what would you recommend for the bleeding issue of the blue pink through the light pink.  I was thinking maybe I needed to prime the whole wall since I am priming all the spots (1/3 wall anyway)?  And, how do I get rid of the brush marks the other guy left; McCormick says to lightly sand before painting.  And, he mucked up the chair railing so I am sanding down and repainting.  Mess.  Please give ideas on all.

Answer (score 0):

I have found than an effective way to get some texture over a patch in drywall is to thin some pre-mix drywall mud with a small amount of water in a paint tray. Then use a long napp paint roller to apply the thinned mud on the wall. You will have to experiment with amount of thinning water to add - I found that it takes only a very small amount. Also you can try rollers with different napps. Lastly to get greatest texture you need to minimize the number of roll overs of a particular area that occur during the mud mixture application.